Is there any explanation on whether Terach knew that Nimrod would kill the slave baby that he substituted for Avrohom
It seems that Nimrod changed drastically over time to become so narcissitic and murderous. I am not clear where Terach sits in the middle of that politically - Is there any explanation or discussions on the close relationship between Terach and Nimrod?Historical story R. Nissin Mindel Z'l How was Terach viewed on the balance as a rasha or a tzadik? Did Terach know that Nimrod would violently murder the slave child Terach exchanged for Avrohom his son (subterfuge) or was Nimrod's wicked response a surprise to Terach - perhaps in those days that type of thing was accepted/common in that era? (Horrific but possible?!?) And was there any other option that Terach could have had in that scenario?

Sefer haYashar, parashas Noach contains relevant information. It's a bit of a long reading. Here's a link for a possible starting point as it goes for many paragraphs. Terach was a general of Nimrod's army. Perhaps you can write your own answer based on it. https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Noach.7?vhe=Sefer_HaYashar,_Livorno_1870&lang=bi

It would be helpful if you quoted the story you're referring to or at least edited in a link to it.

Do you understand those are legends, not history?

I added a link.  My underlying question is complex, but is rooted in the above one: If anyone could have CHOSEN to become Avrohom Avinu in those days (loosly requoted by R. A Miller Z'l in shiurim repeatedly), what did Terach and Amalthai do to create the environment for Avrohom to stand up and actually become A.Avinu?  How do you fill that environmental place between dictatorship and moshiach/peace (where we precariously stand now)?  Why is it a "legend" Al Berko (please clarify that classification)  Thank you for the sources included in answers above - I will look into them!

It states in Rashi Bereshit 11:32 about Terach:

Therefore, Scripture calls him dead, for the wicked, even in their lifetime, are called dead

However it also states in Rashi Bereshit 15:15

His father was an idolater, and He announces to him that he will come to him? This teaches you that Terah repented. [from Tan. Shemoth 18]

So he was seen as wicked - in fact Avraham breaks from his philosophy etc...; however, he does repent and become righteous at some point after Avraham leaving and before his own death.
